# Filter Boto3 Object Collection by depth

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to list all folders at given depth level in an s3 bucket.
I can easily filter by Prefix using objects.filter.
Is there a way to limit to a fixed level of depth?
For now I am counting the separator in object URL, but I believe this still requiring fetching the entire list which is expensive for me.

Is there a way to filter by depth server side?

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketName)
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix').all():
   # print(obj.key)
    if  sum([c=='/' for c in obj.key])==1:
        print(obj.key)
```

Comment: Are you aiming to get the immediate files in a sub directory? Or do you need to specify 2/3 levels ? Can be 2 different questions :)

Comment: If just 1 level, then you can optimise your call using `bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix', Delimiter='/').all():` (works for list_objects, should work for `bucket.objects` too)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: ideally I would like to solve for an arbitrary depth; please share your answers

Comment: Does the above work for the 1st level of depth?